# Inserting bullshit in my answer

Tags: discussion

Somebody edited this my answer: https://history.stackexchange.com/a/1625/466 and inserted a nonsence claim that there is no common language between Romania and Moldova. This is a nonsence because the both countries speak the same language, Romanian. I want to know how to secure myself from somilar "corrections" in the future so that my answer not to get perverted.

I also want to know how to revert the edit.

Comment: take a look at http://lazarus.interclue.com/download very useful tool for online writing/recovering.

Comment: Try asking nicely next time...either way its done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not a way to prevent others from changing your posts. The whole point of SE sites is to allow the community to monitor and modify content where appropriate. Sadly, this sometimes means that unnecessary or incorrect edits may end up getting made. I believe you should see a Rollback link below your post. If so, you can click that and it will remove the edits that were made and restore your original content.

For others who may happen to read this, please consider using the Comments area for radical changes to a post. If you are making simple grammar or spelling changes, that's not a problem, but even then you should leave a comment on the editing screen to indicate what you changed and why. If you see something you deem to be considerably inaccurate, then comment on it and let the community help decide how to handle it.

Comment: There is no "rollback" link.

Comment: If you select the datestamp where it says Edited you get an option to see all previous revisions, Moderators have this and others with enough Rep get this as well.

Comment: Sadly, "simple grammar fixes" can't be done because of the stupid "at least 6 characters" limit.

Comment: @Lohoris - Well...you could always make your simple fix along with 20 exteranious `X`s, and then make another edit delting the `X`s.

Comment: @T.E.D. cool workaround, which makes that limit even more stupid than it already was.